# debug version of react native Android app works, assembleRelease fails

Tags: react-native

I'm able to build the debug version of my react-native app.  However, when I try to build the release apk, I get the following error:

> Execution failed for task ':blelibrary:verifyReleaseResources'.
>
> > java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource
> >     linking failed   Output: 
> >     /Users/someguy/projects/third/someapp/android/blelibrary/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/values-v26/values-v26.xml:7:
> >     error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.

followed by a ton of messages that look like this:

> Command:
>   /Users/someguy/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.5.0-alpha03-5252756-osx.jar/8bd335ec556ebe5abcc696b2317758fe/aapt2-3.5.0-alpha03-5252756-osx/aapt2
>   link -I\
>             /Users/someguy/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-24/android.jar\
>             --manifest\

app build gradle looks like this

```
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.oliveapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 35
        versionName "1.3.5"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
        packagingOptions {
            exclude "lib/arm64-v8a/libgnustl_shared.so"
        }
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                arguments '-DANDROID_STL=c++_static'
            }
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
            storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
            keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }

        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path 'CMakeLists.txt'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-i18n')
    implementation project(':react-native-svg')
    implementation project(':react-native-extra-dimensions-android')
    implementation project(':react-native-google-analytics-bridge')
    implementation project(':react-native-splash-screen')
    implementation project(':react-native-image-picker')
    implementation project(':react-native-spinkit')
    implementation project(':react-native-fbsdk')
    implementation project(':react-native-picker')
    implementation 'cn.aigestudio.wheelpicker:WheelPicker:1.1.2'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
    implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
    // From node_modules
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:2.0.0'
    implementation project(':blelibrary')
    implementation project(':gaialibrary')
    implementation project(':vmupgradelibrary')
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta2'
    implementation project(':react-native-connectivity-status')

    implementation('com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.0.0')
    implementation('com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.0.0')
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
    implementation("androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01")
    implementation("androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.1.0-rc01")
    implementation("androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0-rc01")
    implementation("androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0-rc01")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.1.0-rc01")
    implementation("androidx.core:core:1.1.0-rc01")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.1.0-rc01")
    implementation("androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.1.0-rc01")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.1.0-rc01")
    implementation("androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.0-rc01")

}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

repositories {
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://github.com/500px/500px-android-blur/raw/master/releases/' }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
    }
}
// apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

after running ./gradlew assembleRelease --info
I saw this message:

```
> > Task :app:externalNativeBuildRelease  Task ':app:externalNativeBuildRelease' is not up-to-date because:   Task
> has not declared any outputs. externalNativeBuildRelease: starting
> build externalNativeBuildRelease: reading expected JSONs
> externalNativeBuildRelease: done reading expected JSONs
> externalNativeBuildRelease: executing build commands for targets that
> produce .so files or executables externalNativeBuildRelease: evaluate
> miniconfig externalNativeBuildRelease: evaluate library
> lib_someappfitting-Release-armeabi-v7a externalNativeBuildRelease: not
> building target lib_someappfitting because there was no build command
> for it externalNativeBuildRelease: evaluate library
> someappfittingjni-Release-armeabi-v7a externalNativeBuildRelease:
> building target library someappfittingjni because no targets are
> specified. externalNativeBuildRelease: about to build
> /Users/someguy/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/bin/cmake --build
> /Users/someguy/projects/third/someapp-app/android/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/release/armeabi-v7a
> --target someappfittingjni externalNativeBuildRelease: evaluate miniconfig externalNativeBuildRelease: evaluate library
> lib_someappfitting-Release-x86 externalNativeBuildRelease: not
> building target lib_someappfitting because there was no build command
> for it externalNativeBuildRelease: evaluate library
> someappfittingjni-Release-x86 externalNativeBuildRelease: building
> target library someappfittingjni because no targets are specified.
> externalNativeBuildRelease: about to build
> /Users/someguy/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/bin/cmake --build
> /Users/someguy/projects/third/someapp-app/android/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/release/x86
> --target someappfittingjni Build someappfittingjni x86 externalNativeBuildRelease: Executable :
> /Users/someguy/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/bin/cmake
> arguments : 
> --build /Users/someguy/projects/third/someapp-app/android/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/release/x86
> --target someappfittingjni
```

Comment: Update the compileSdkVersion to 28 in blelibrary's build.gradle.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to the android build.gradle:

```
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion 28     // have to match with build.gradle and app/build.gradle ones
                buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'  // have to match with build.gradle and app/build.gradle ones
                variantFilter { variant ->
                    def names = variant.flavors*.name
                    // To check for a certain build type, use variant.buildType.name == "<buildType>"
                    if (names.contains("reactNative51") || names.contains("reactNative55") || names.contains("reactNative56")) {
                        // Gradle ignores any variants that satisfy the conditions above.
                        setIgnore(true)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Check out this [page](https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage/issues/49) for more details